# Every time variable updates store value inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble adding a variable to an array, every time I push the variable to an array it keeps changing,

```
i = 5;

function setValue() {
  let a = [];
  a.push(i);
  console.log(a);
}

setValue();
```

It has to be the same variable, in the app I'm working on is a variable that keeps track of your savings in shopping cart.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you've written, or at least a reproducible example?

Comment: You'll have to push `2` as well. BTW I can't reproduce your example. [Changing the value of `number`](https://jsfiddle.net/tzy2h6qb/) doesn't mean that the value in the array also changes.

Comment: do you push the values while inside a foreach or something?, otherwise you won't get the result you want, it would be better if we could see some relevant code and show us your attempt

Comment: Again, this has to be inside an iteration, just changing the value of i, won't really add a different value to your old one

Comment: @ChrisG qucik example to set me in the right direction?

Comment: for example, inside your setValue() function you wrote `let a = [];` that means everytime that functions runs, your "a" variable will reset and it will never store new values

Comment: You should improve your question... Include enough info and code so people can help you instead of wasting their time guessing what you left out...

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you have to understand the context and the scope.

In your case you are creating a function. So you are creating a new local context and local scope and in this local context you are defining an array.

The `setValue()` function is executed, but when the execution ends
this local context is removed. And all declared variables are removed too.

So you execute `setValue()` again you are creating other context with new variables (local scope.) So the array `a` is created again, and you are changing it with the second function call.

To fix your error, you need to [learn about context and scope in JavaScript](https://hackernoon.com/learn-javascript-fundamentals-local-scope-ebxo33fj).

Answer (score 0):

For example let's say all the values you want to store inside your a variable are inside this array

```
const array = [1,2,7,24,8];
let a = [];//initialize a here
```

Iterate thru that array of values, this iteration might change depending on how you get your data, since I don't know Im just using array as an example

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    setValue(array[i]);//run your function on each iteration
}
```

Your function changed to this:

```
function setValue(val) {
  a.push(val);
}
```

your output:

```
console.log(a);//output: [1, 2, 7, 24, 8]
```

Edit: If the numbers you want to add come from an input then you can do it like this(this approach uses jquery):

```
<input type="number" id="my_input">
```

your js:

```
let a = [];//Declare a outside onchange function
 
//Onchange function to catch the new value everytime input number changes
$("#my_input").on("change", function() {
   var input = $(this).val();//new value from input
   setValue(parseFloat(input));//parseFloat convert string to number and setValue to run your function
   console.log(a);// output
});
```

Your function:

```
function setValue(val) {
  a.push(val);//adds new value to array a
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/5dmsLry0/60/